# Django: templatedoesnotexist gis/admin/openlayers.html

Tags: django, geodjango

Here is the error:

```
templatedoesnotexist gis/admin/openlayers.html
```

I get the following error when I run my django admin. How can I fix?

I have django installed.

Answer (score 112):

Add `'django.contrib.gis'` to `INSTALLED_APPS`.

Answer (score 31):

I added `'django.contrib.gis'` to `INSTALLED_APPS` in the django `settings.py` and it fixed my problem .